# Kentico 13 Xperience View Component displaying Page Type field data

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, kentico

If I had a page type called "MySite.TextBox" and it had two fields: "Title" and "Content" what all would be required for me to make a view component that pulls all page types from the site searching from "/" and looking down to have it appear as a list of items in any view, including the layout view, using something like <vc: text-box-list > in a view, such as the _layout

What files would I need to create aside from the TextBoxList view component?

I know I'll need to make a generated code file for the MySite.TextBox page type. But it's where I set up and establish the rules for outputting the list that things get fuzzy.

For instance if I wanted to establish rules like:

```
var textBoxList = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments("MySite.TextBox").TopN(5).Path("/", PathTypeEnum.Children).OrderByAscending("Title").ToList();
```

Would that be a part of the view component or something else?

I would just really really love to have an example. I hate that the Dancing Goat and Medio Clinic sites do not have one.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Follow the below to Create a widget -**

https://docs.xperience.io/developing-websites/page-builder-development/developing-widgets

**2. Retrieves pages of multiple page types from the '/' section of the content tree:**

```
var pages = pageRetriever.RetrieveMultiple(multiDocumentQuery => multiDocumentQuery
.Path("/", PathTypeEnum.Children));
```

Reference:
https://docs.xperience.io/custom-development/working-with-pages-in-the-api#WorkingwithpagesintheAPI-Retrievingpagesonthelivesite

**3. Retrieve Common data from multiple page types**

```
var commondata=Pageretriver.RetriveMultiple(multiDocumentQuery=> multiDocumentQuery
.Types("PageType1","PageType2)
.WithCoupledColumns())
.Select(page=> new <desiredobject name>
{
fieldName=page.GetString("fieldName")
});
```

Reference
https://docs.xperience.io/custom-development/working-with-pages-in-the-api/reference-documentquery-methods